# Protecting ADC Input inrush current

Tags: current, resistors, adc, zener, inrush-current

I'm currently using a 5V [current transducer](https://www.crmagnetics.com/dc-current-transducers/cr5210) that's connecting to an I/O device ADC input. I'm trying to protect my ADC input from going over 5V by using a [zener diode](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/NZX5V1C-133/2762656) . The reason this is coming about, is a current I'm trying to measure has a high inrush current on start up, and I don't want to damage the system. On the zener datasheet, it says \$I_z=5mA\$

Does this mean it will only starts clamping at 5mA or does it mean it will not work after 5mA?

And is it necessary to have a current limiting resistor? What will happened if there's no resistor?

Comment: This is not a problem. The 5V transducer can't output more than 5V.

Comment: I accidentally hookup the wrong current yesterday and it outputs a 13V tho.

Comment: Really? Are you sure you have the 5V version?

Comment: yes. I have the CR5210-0.5 version

Comment: That's really weird. Does it actually measure correctly? Current limiting resistor not necessary if your diode is big enough or the drive current is weak enough. The zener just won't clamp to spec if current is <5mA.

Comment: I think so? I accidentally hookup a 1.9A to my 0.5A model and it outputs a 13V but I turnoff immediately. What do you mean by diode is big enough? Like current rating or?

Comment: Oh, diode power rating.

Comment: So when I tested this without the resistor, the diode is not clamping i think. When i put in a 5.7V, i got a 5.4V when I measure across the diode. Is there any reason for this? When I add a 75ohm resistor, it kinda clamps but it went to 5.2V @6V input and 5.3V@ 8.5V input

Comment: It is because of the IV curve of a diode. It's not ideal so eases into the voltage drop as current increases before suddenly increasing rapidly. Google a zener diode curve. It's an exponential, not a brick wallAt 8.5V enough current is being driven to be in the vertical portion of the diode IV curve.

Comment: @DKNguyen My experience is similar with getting over the rated output.  It's only specified to be linear in the stated range (5v in OP example), but will output higher, just not linear.

Comment: @Aaron Good to know. I would have expected that behaviour with a current transformer but not a hall sensor.

Comment: Okay. After a few testing, I think the main reason is the leakage current from my zener diode is causing some voltage drop that's affecting my ADC input. On the zener datasheet, it only shows me at 2V, there's a 2uA leakage current. But when I tested with 5V, i have around 220uA. Is this normal to have such big jump and is there any way to solve this? Most of the other zener diode I found online also only listed their leakage current at 1V/2V instead of their max 5V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't show the I/V curve for the breakdown region in the datasheet, but for a diode in zener mode, it breaks down very fast as the voltage is increased (Vz in diagram below)

[image]
Source: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html

The Iz point means that they set the current to 5mA and then measured the voltage Vz at that point. The intended application is more for setting a voltage so if you wanted to get a specific Vz (for a specific model) then set the Iz to 5mA, increase the current beyond 5mA and you get a cliff. So use a current limiting resistor *before the zener* to keep the current below the absolute maximum ratings of the diode.

You don't necessarily need a resistor, if the highest potential current that the zener would ever see was low enough to keep the part from over heating ( like from an opamp that could source up to 80mA on the output) then a 5V diode would dissipate P = 0.08*5V = 0.4W which is just under the max dissipation for the part which is 0.5W